# SalesForce canvas app oauth web server flow with minimal user interaction

Tags: oauth, salesforce

So I'm weighing up the pros/cons of the different auth mechanisims for a SalesForce Canvas application.

First, a little background. I've got an existing web app - let's call it "myapp". I setup a VisualForce tab containing a VisualForce page which embeds my canvas app by the following approach:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:canvasApp applicationName="___________" />
</apex:page>
```

I first implemented access via the signed request method, which was great, as the user only had to accept my app's permissions on first access, and subsequent attempts to access my canvas app could jump right in to myapp homepage.

From reading [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2014/04/packaging-canvas-apps-for-different-editions.html) about packaging canvas apps for different SalesForce editions, signed request method has a limitation:

> Most typical Group and Professional Edition customers are not going tobe able to use your Signed Request Connected App unless they upgrade to EE or higher or purchase these features as an add-on.

So I decided to switch to the oauth workflows.

Looking at the [user agent oauth flow documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US), it says:

> The user must always approve access for this authentication flow. After approving access, the application receives the callback from Salesforce.

This is also not desirable, however [the web server oauth flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm) does not have that requirement - once a user accepts the app's permission requirements, they don't need to be prompted to do that again. It also makes things like adding a "Login with SalesForce" option on myapp's login page super easy to add in.

So I setup the web server oauth flow, and have everything functioning well, and as an added benefit added a "Login with SalesForce" option to my login page - great.

Next step was to set the canvas app in the VisualForce tab up to kick off the web server oauth flow.

## The problem I want to solve:

I want to use the web server oauth flow to gain access to the homepage of myapp from that VisualForce tab, with as few user interactions as possible in the process.

### Base setup

To initiate the oauth flow, I've setup a URL with the following logic in there to make it simple to craft links that kick off the process from elsewhere. This is used from each of the below examples, and is referenced by links to `/salesforce/oauth/.....`.

```
// Allow links to this page to specify "state" and "prompt" paramaters.
$state  = isset($_GET['state'])  ? $_GET['state']  : 'login';
$prompt = isset($_GET['prompt']) ? $_GET['prompt'] : '';

// Canvas app contextual information provides the right SalesForce endpoint domain, so provide a way for that to be passed in here, or fallback to standard login.salesforce.com for other workflows.
$authDomain = isset($_GET['authDomain']) ? $_GET['authDomain'] : 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize';

$url = $authDomain.'?'.http_build_query(array(
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'client_id'     => 'XXXXXXX_MY_APP_CLIENT_ID',
    'redirect_uri'  => 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/salesforce/authorize/',
    'state'         => $state,
    'prompt'        => $prompt,
));

header('Location: '.$url);
die;
```

### Failed attempt 1

Using the javascript canvas sdk, redirect the canvas app to initiate my web server oauth flow:

```
location.href = '/salesforce/oauth?authUrl='+encodeURIComponent(Sfdc.canvas.oauth.loginUrl())+'&state=canvas';
```

I ran into two problems with this approach:

1. The canvas app looses the contextual information provided by the #query fragment in it's URL.
2. `X-Frame-Options` header of the SalesForce page which has the accept/decline permissions prevent it from displaying within an iframe, **even on SalesForce domains**.

I feel this would be the best way to accomplish my goal if these issues could be overcome.

I actually did an experiment which resolves issue #1 by loading that URL in another iframe, within my canvas app, and if I'd already accepted myapps permission requirements that worked flawlessly, however I was still stuck with issue #2 when the permissions screen popped up and the whole process failed to complete.

### Current solution

I've made the initial canvas app page include a button to click, which opens the web server oauth flow in a new window where it completes successfully. Upon completion, the canvas app iframe is redirected to my app homepage.

I'm unhappy with this, because every time I click on my VisualForce tab, there's a step in there requiring the user to click a button, and a new window pops up to run the oauth workflow. It closes itself automatically with no extra user interaction if the user had already accepted the app permissions in the past, or prompts them to accept if they hadn't yet, and then closes itself.

If I'm stuck with this solution it's not the end of the world - we'll make that button into a splash screen with some marketing crap in there and a big obnoxious "Continue to MyApp" button somewhere.

### The question (...finally)

Is there some way I can remove that necessary step of clicking the button every single time the canvas app is loaded, but continue using the web server oauth flow here? (remembering I don't want to use the user agent oauth flow because that has a similar requirement of accepting the permissions every time the user accesses it anyway).

That extra step is particularly annoying when the canvas app is being embedded within a SalesForce account or contact screen - as it stops my app from loading and displaying data to my users until the user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either I don't get it, or that's really simple. You need to use oAuth `immediate` parameter:

> immediate — Determines whether the user should be prompted for login and approval. This parameter is optional. The value must be true or false if specified. Default value is false. Note the following:
>   If set to true, and if the user is currently logged in and has previously approved the client_id, Salesforce skips the approval step.
>   If set to true and the user is not logged in or has not previously approved the client, Salesforce immediately terminates with the immediate_unsuccessful error code.

Source: [1](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm), [2](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)

The only catch is the last part: you will receive error if user hasn't authorized your app yet. In my experience with oAuth it's really easier to use Javascript to run your requests from the client's browser itself. You can fire off `immediate = true` request, and right after it `immediate = false` in case first one failed. Then you send the `access_token` to your app by creating third request – to your own server.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that. Sounds very promising - thank you. I'll experiment today with this approach, and post back later with results.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance - got that working and everything looks great :)